# how to load images in sdl to a surface in c using IMG_Load?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-image

When I run

```
SDL_Surface* surface  = IMG_Load("*image location*");
```

an error pops up saying

> initialization of 'SDL_Surface *' {aka 'struct SDL_Surface *'} from 'int' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

I don't know why this happening because shouldn't IMG_load be returning a pointer

https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_11.html

here is the rest of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <SDL2\SDL.h>

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    int result = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("bruh",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,500,500,0);
    SDL_Renderer *rend  =  SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_Surface* surface  = IMG_Load("*image location*");
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend,surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_RenderClear(rend);
    SDL_RenderCopy(rend,texture,NULL,NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    SDL_Delay(5000);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0; 
}
```

how do I fix this error?

Comment: Warning: I have zero knowledge about SDL. Note: Did you had a look at [this sample](https://github.com/MetaCipher/sdl-2.0-basics/blob/master/App.cpp) ?

Comment: @fpiette i dont know c++ . what is the problem ?

Comment: The error message says that `IMG_Load` returns an int and you assign it to a `SDL_Surface*`. One possibility is that you have somewhere the wrong definition for ÌMG_Load`. Search for it in the headers you have.

Comment: @sababugs112 C and C++ are the same thing except C++ has extra OOP feature and a bigger standard library and a few things here and there. I'm absolutely shocked when someone who knows C/C++ says that he/she doesn't know the other. How much more than 5 minutes will it take to know a bit about the other language?

Comment: @SmGreatC C and C++ are completely different languages. Many C programs are invalid C++ programs and vice versa. They share a common history from 40 years ago, but that's about it. (And in fact, sababugs112 code above is buggy but valid C, while it would be invalid C++).

Comment: @spectras Yes, I know. It's just a few things here and there and the fixes are simple. And the similarity of a language is not calculated by how good it is compiled by the other language's compiler only. It depends upon the syntax as well which is almost the same with C and C++. Yes, they are different languages but it's so easy to learn one if you know the other, it makes no sense to not know the other.

Comment: A few examples of not-so-simply fixable things: `#define cbrt(X) _Generic((X), long double: cbrtl, default: cbrt, float: cbrtf)(X)`, `int array[argc]`, `auto x = 0.5;`, `*(double*)charArray`. But you are right, it is not just the syntax: the whole paradigms used and made available by the languages are completely different. Good luck implementing something like `compose(func1, func2, func3)(input)` in C.

Answer (score 2):

[`IMG_Load`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image.html#SEC11) belongs to separate libary [`SDL_image`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/). This function is [declared in `SDL_image.h`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL_image/blob/main/SDL_image.h#L97), which you didn't include. Add that include and link with appropriate library. In C undeclared functions are allowed via implicit declarations, and implicitly declared function returns `int`, that's where your error comes from.

Sane compiler will issue a warning about implicit declaration. Warnings are there for a reason, read them and don't suppress warnings unless you're absolutely certain.